# Is there a rails3-compatible emacs mode yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, elisp, ruby-on-rails-3

Rinari hasn't been updated in the last few months, and there doesn't seem to be such progress made in the branches on github.
I've never tried emacs-rails, but from what I can see, the same applies.

So, is there a rails mode somewhere that's compatible with v3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the Rinari maintainers now that Eric Schulte has stepped down, but there's no active project lead.

Johan Andersson is taking the initiative and has started to work on making Rinari compatible with Rails 3:

http://groups.google.com/group/emacs-on-rails/browse_thread/thread/bfa01830ec6584f1

When there's something to see, I'll merge it into a branch or the mainline of the official Rinari tree at http://github.com/eschulte/rinari. In the meantime, if you have any feedback or desire to help, please join the above group.

Comment: will be watching, not sur I'll be able to help though. thanks !

Comment: @sanityinc ,thank you your job. Would you like update rinari to newest in Elpa?

Comment: @HelloWorld There are already up-to-date packages for Rinari on Marmalade (marmalade-repo.org) and snapshot packages are also available in Melpa (melpa.milkbox.net).

Comment: @ayckoster Yes, there are plenty of people using Rinari with Rails 3 apps.